# wkhtmltopdf html url encoding (german umlaut)

Tags: encoding, utf-8, wkhtmltopdf

encoding of the following .pdf conversion on the linux console fails with "ContentNotFoundError"

```
wkhtmltopdf --page-size A4 --encoding utf-8 --viewport-size 1024x768 http://localhost/möja.html /tmp/test.pdf
```

Same problem in lynx with enabled UTF-8 charset:

```
The requested URL /mÃ¶ja.html was not found on this server.
```

locale settings are in utf-8. Console is typing the german special chars correctly.

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Accessing the page over the browser and with wkhtmltopdf on the development system (same debian wheezy distribution) is working as expected. pdf's would be created fine without german special chars in the url. I can't find any differences.

Thank you for every hint!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the *server* doesn't expect to see UTF-8 encoded characters, it probably expects Latin-1. URLs cannot contain non-ASCII characters to begin with. Encode the umlaut in the URL in percent encoding according to the expected character encoding. The Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) percent encoded version would be:

```
http://localhost/k%F6nig.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. On my development system i don't have to encode the uri. Here the following bash command works: lynx http://localhost/könig.html. On my productive system even the lynx interface is not showing umlauts.

Comment: The web server receives this URL and will have to look for files on its disk that match the file name. How the file system handles non-ASCII characters very much depends on the file system. On some systems file names may be UTF-8 encoded, on others UTF-16, on others they'll have some complicated codepage. The encoding of the URL needs to match the encoding of the file on disk (unless there's some middle layer on the server which handles this differently). This perfectly explains why it works on one system and not another. It also explains why you should avoid non-ASCII characters in URLs.

Comment: Thank you, but on Unix-like systems, the encoding of file names is not set at the filesystem level, but rather in the user environment.

Comment: I think there must be a problem with my configuration because if i change localt to 'de', even the lynx system interface can't show correct latin characters

Comment: The URL will be sent as percent encoded string, even if you type "ö" on your command line. How it will be percent encoded depends on your locale and console settings. You type "ö" into your console, which will be represented in some specifics bytes depending on your console settings, which will be interpreted by the set locale, which will then be encoded into `%xx%xx` by curl. The server receives `%xx%xx`, which represents bytes, and attempts to find a filename with the same bytes in its filename on its disk. And it fails. Locales do not matter to the server. URLs don't have locales.